# Seagate External Hard zero size

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a seagate external hard disk and recently I encountered some problem with that. I am using both windows and Ubuntu environment and my hard disk detecting on both but, in windows it's says the location not available and ubuntu giving some other error message when trying to mount. **"Error mounting the partition"**

I'm afraid of loosing my data on that disk,could any one please help?

is there any way to make to work and retrieve some data from that?

Comment: First step: Is your harddisk detected in the BIOS or in UEFI. Does that show a size (if not the disk is broken). If it is then check the contents of the partition table to see if those got mangled.

(That is assuming that you can remove theextrenal drive from the case and mount it via a regular SAS or SATA port)

Comment: It sounds like the drive has started to fail.  Your options are limited, in both cases, your drive isn't being mounted even though you are getting different errors ( the cause of the error is the same ).

Comment: @Hennes In Ubuntu disk management tool hard disk detecting with exact size and can see the content occupied as bar graphic. I'm not able to attach the photo to show the exact error but when trying to mount it says mounting error in Ubuntu. Is there any tool to fix the problem

Comment: You are trying to go too fast. Step 1) Does the physycal disk work? Step 2) Does it contain valid partitions? And only then step 3) Are those partitions correct or corrupted and reported as 0 size.  Validate the base steps first.

Comment: Its possible only the enclosure usb interface has failed, remove the drive from the enclosure, if it does Not have a proprietary connector, simply connect the drive using a different usb to hard drive adapter, see if you can see your data now.

Comment: I completely agree with all the suggestions in the above comments and you should try them all , but just want to add that since this is an external HDD, the problem might be with the USB cable or port that you are using. If the HDD isn't getting enough power it might start to behave strange. You might also try connecting it to a different system.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Will try and update the result